# Login with extra permission with Facebook SDK 3 for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I followed the step of "Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login" section at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ The login process is fine. Because I would like to use the native Android button for a user to log in, I modify the code slightly by moving the following code into a View.OnClickListener() of a native Android button. The following is the code in the listener:

```
Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session,SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {                           
            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API
                // response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + user.getName() +" "+user.getId()+"!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The onActivityResult() and AndroidManifest.xml is the same as the tutorial

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

However, I would like to request get "read_friendlists" when a user logs in successfully. I read the tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ but it uses Facebook SDK customized button. How can I achieve the same behavior with a native Android button like my code shown above?

Comment: [Have a look at this post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-friends/);

Comment: @Adil Thank you! After reading this, I think the downside of the tutorial (or the SDK?) in my case is that it encapsulates too much details under the hood. Therefore, it is not easy for developer to leverage the SDK into custom program flows and UIs. Take https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ for another example. The login button provided by SDK is easy to use but hard for me to customize the UI and maintain its implementation/function. I think the view and control should be separated.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm using a game engine and not using any android views, just using opengl, I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered a similar question on another post.  My solution allows you to use a native button and request additional read permissions when the user first logs in.  Check it out here [Ask for more permissions with 3.0 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13926065/703910)