# Requesting a login when Facebook session is expired

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I tried revoking the permissions from the Facebook apps list. The LoginButton turned off and became "Login" when `Session.getActiveSession()` is called and returns `AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED`.

Is it possible to show the login page (and start the LoginActivity) programatically?
Or should the user press the LoginButton manually?

Comment: well if you want to login the user when the session expire try to open again the session

Comment: Did you open the session again manually? According to this, according to a Facebook engineer, it is much simpler to use the LoginButton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897056/when-to-request-permissions-with-facebooks-new-android-sdk-3-0 because "since you will have to do all the session management by hand" otherwise.

Comment: yes whenever i call an activity that uses facebook i try to open the session then close it after i get the data that i need