# Facebook Android sdk 3.0 : session is null on Activity result

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-android-sdk

I try to upgrade Facebook Android sdk from 2.0 to 3.0, but I encounter an issue, here is my case :

I have a webview, and I execute the following code when user click on the "Facebook Login" :

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = act.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String access_token =  mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null){
     session = new Session(act.getApplicationContext());
     if(access_token != null){
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
      editor.putString("access_token", null);
      editor.commit();
      AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(access_token,null, null, null, null);
          session.open(accessToken, callback);
      Session.setActiveSession(session);
     }
}
Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(act);
String[] permissions = {"email, user_likes, user_checkins, publish_checkins, publish_stream"};
request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissions));
request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
request.setCallback(callback);
session.openForPublish(request);
```

and on the same class (which extends Activity), I got this code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

When user click the button, all is working fine : the facebook dialog opens, permissions are required, and dialog close.
The problem is that Session.getActiveSession() returns null, instead of returning the instanciated one. In detail, it's returns this :

```
{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to request permissions with Facebook's new Android SDK 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897056/when-to-request-permissions-with-facebooks-new-android-sdk-3-0)

Comment: Have you found the cause of your problem? Or have you fixed it by using the information from the possibly duplicate question? In any case, please post your answer here, because I googled for the exact same problem and was brought here :)

Comment: @sm4 have you sorted out the prob? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @VenomVendor - try upgrading to newer version of the SDK.

Comment: I have updated to latest version, it was working earlier. I am getting access tokens. But `request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent`

Comment: Even I'm facing same problem with Facebook sdk 3.5.2 latest as of now... And moreover I get this error on some devices and not on other... Tried all permutations but no successful hit... plz help